# Passing Variables Through JQuery Click Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables

How can I pass a variable from one click function to the other through JQuery?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

       var n = 1;

        $('#Next').click(function() { 
        var nn = n++;

            });

        $('#Previous').click(function() { 

        alert(nn);

          });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have a variable in a higher scope, use that, otherwise `data()` would be a better approach.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var n = 1;

    $('#Next').click(function() { 
        n++;
    });

    $('#Previous').click(function() { 
        alert(n);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
var nn = n++;
```

with

```
n++;
```